# Can't start a XEN VM - VM name already exists

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, xen

I've setup xen on ubuntu, created a couple of vms, started and stopped them. But now when I try to start one of them I get:

VmError: VM name 'vps.lisignoli.net' already exists

It doesn't show up on xl list.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without knowing what command you're using to try to start it.  If you're using a "create" command you might try "start" instead - create loads from a config file, but if the config is already loaded, it might just need a "start".  Sounds like you're using xl instead of xm?